# How to optimize reducer function

Tags: javascript, logic, javascript-objects

I have this function

```
const joinCages = arr => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, { jaulaId, comunaCode }) => {
        if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(jaulaId)) acc[jaulaId] = []
        acc[jaulaId].push(comunaCode)
        return acc
    }, {})
}
```

The **output** is this:

```
{
  JAU0000001: [ '130109' ],
  JAU0000029: [ '100102', '100103' ],
  JAU0000017: [ '100304', '100305' ]
}
```

**What it does:**

Create an object that group the "Comuna Code" in the key "jaula ID" from an array of objects

**Data array**

```
[
    {
        indexId: 104834,
        jaulaId: "JAU0000001",
        distributionCenterId: "100",
        comunaCode: "130109",
        orderType: "Retorno",
        regionCode: "13"
    },
    {
        indexId: 104836,
        jaulaId: "JAU0000029",
        distributionCenterId: "100",
        comunaCode: "100102",
        orderType: "Retorno",
        regionCode: "13"
    },
    {
        indexId: 104837,
        jaulaId: "JAU0000029",
        distributionCenterId: "100",
        comunaCode: "100103",
        orderType: "Retorno",
        regionCode: "13"
    }
]
```

I want to upgrade that function without the if statement and removing the return...Return implicit you know?

The problem is that I am failing coding this and I dont know where or how can I do this.

**Upgraded function**

```
const joinCages2 = arr => {
    return arr.reduce((acc, { jaulaId, comunaCode }) => ({
        ...acc,
        [jaulaId]: [jaulaId] ? [jaulaId].push(comunaCode) : [comunaCode]
    }), {})
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `const joinCage2 = arr => arr.reduce((acc, {jaulaId, comunaCode}) => ({...acc, [jaulaId]: [...(acc[jaulaId] || []), comunaCode]}), {})`?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Already tried that :(
TypeError: acc[jaulaId] is not iterable

Any ideas?

Comment: Try edited one. Seems to work.

Comment: You are mi GOD. Dude thank you SO much.
Now...Can you explain how this works and why? I'm trying to improve mi coding skills but when i search for this kind of operations, i mean implicit returns and stuff cant get nothing so its hard to understando how to do that :/

Comment: Initially, your `acc` is an empty object, so `acc[jaulaId]` is `undefined`, hence the error when you tried to spread that. To avoid that kind of error for the first occurrence of `jaulaId` you employ [short-circuit OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation) to fallback for empty array which spreads w/o error.

Comment: And, by the way, I wouldn't call that kind of refactoring an *upgrade* since you screwed both performance and readability, compared to your initial code.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov nice code! I would also suggest to use nullish coalescing '??' instead of or '||' because it's more save in some minor cases.

Comment: Here is something compact https://jsfiddle.net/o8baes4L/

Comment: @AlexGusev : Fair point, regarding nullish coalescing (though, we're not expecting `0` or `''`). It's just a muscle memory to use `||`.

Comment: Wow, you know a lot haha. Thank you guys! 
@YevgenGorbunkov, how can you tell that code will screwed performance?
kemicofaghost, dont understand your code :/. I will study more

thank you ALL

Comment: @Programmer89 Compact snippet recreates `acc` object along with `acc[jualaId]` array upon each iteration of a loop, whereas your initial code was mutating them. Thus, for input array of 1k items, your initial code will perform about [80 times faster](https://jsbench.me/2nkvlfkpx6/1).